# serial port receiving data manipulation

Tags: c#

In my application I am receiving data serially from com3 it is an integer variable, now I want to transfer this data in a form of string to com1 the string will be like "#0 Pa" here a is integer value received from 'com3'.

I know how to receive and send data serially my code is working fine with it, but I am struck how can I form string code so it automatically take integer value received from com3 and send to com1, basically how I can formed string with a variable value received and some character which are constant.

Answer (score 2):

My question is: how do you receive the integer? Usually data is transferred as strings.

In case you do have it as an integer,

```
int receivedPar = ...;
string messageToSend = string.Format("#0 P{0}", receivedPar);
```